# I keep fantasizing about my future wife resulting in the release of mazi and it touching my clothes. Can I offer my prayers in this state?

Tags: fiqh, nikah, sex, taharah

I have my soon to be wife in Pakistan and we talk on Skype while I'm in USA. 
She is very Islamic and we never had any bad conversation or anything that we are not allowed to speak about before marriage. Everytime we speak I get some liquid which is not semen as its lighter than that. I have no bad intentions about her but yes, I fantasize having sex at the back of my mind but when I speak to her,I don't do so because I want to have sex. I speak to her because I like her and I want to be with her for the rest of my life.

I can't offer my prayers and am worried about it a lot. She keeps asking me why am I not offering my prayers and I am shy to tell her openly. But I told her a little bit and she was so upset that she stopped eating and started crying a lot. She is chaste and pure soul and I don't want to hurt her.

Please tell me what is happening with me and if I can offer my prayers with that liquid touching my clothes?

Answer (score 7):

It is [wajib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wajib) for a mature man or woman to observe their prayers. Indeed, the Prophet has informed us that it is the prayers that would be the first deeds to be checked on the day of judgement:

> "The first matter that the slave will be brought to account for on the
>   Day of Judgment is the prayer. If it is sound, then the rest of his
>   deeds will be sound. And if it is bad, then the rest of his deeds will
>   be bad."

With regards to the preseminal fluid, you can sprinkle water on your clothes, wash your entire organ, and pray in them after performing ablution. This is because the religion is meant to be easy, and this is a very common thing that people face, especially the young.

> “I used to experience a lot of urethral discharge, and I used to do
>   ghusl a lot. I asked the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) about it and he said: ‘It is sufficient for you to
>   do wudoo’ (to purify yourself) from that.’ I said, ‘O Messenger of
>   Allaah, what about when it gets on my clothes?’ He said: ‘It is
>   sufficient for you to take a handful of water and sprinkle it on your
>   clothes wherever you think (the madhiy) is.’” (Reported by
>   al-Tirmidhi. He said: This is a saheeh hasan hadeeth, and the only
>   other hadeeth about madhiy that we know is the hadeeth of Muhammad ibn
>   Ishaaq).

You musn't slack in offering your prayers and must also improve your knowledge of the deen and also importantly, you should hasten your marriage so that you don't fall into forbidden things with your to-be wife. Read more in http://islamqa.info/en/2458.