# About pre ejaculation fluid

Tags: sex, taharah

I am 29 years old man.Not married. For many days I m getting problem with pre - ejaculation fluid. Everyday my penis erect before urinating or it was already erected when I get up early morning to pray fajr prayer. I have noticed when my penis get flaccid lot of pre - ejaculation fluid comes off when performing salat.I have broken salat so many times and washed penis. So, my question is do I need to break salat when it seem to me that fluid is coming out or shall I continue salat. And do I need gush everytime or wash the cloth 
Any advice would be great. It will help me out of this problem inshallah.

Comment: Checkk this out... [If I have urine on my clothes but do not know it?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/if-i-have-urine-on-my-clothes-but-do-not-know-it) and [I keep fantasizing about my future wife…](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15033/i-keep-fantasizing-about-my-future-wife-resulting-in-the-release-of-mazi-and-it/15035?s=3|0.0000#15035) & [Whimsy about the status of my wudhu is affecting my salah](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/whimsy-about-the-status-of-my-wudhu-is-affecting-my-salah/11036?s=8|0.0000#11036)

Comment: i think you should try to emit it all before salat, before taharat, after urination, try to change sitting position of urinating, to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Neither washing yourself or your clothes, nor performing the wudu again is required if

1. wadi (liquid discharged after urination)
2. wazi (liquid seen after ejaculation)
3. mazi (moisture discharged by a man during wooing, courtship, etc)

is discharged. They are not najs nor do they break the wudu.

(Related [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10509/3487))

**Reference from Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani:**
[Taharat » Istibra](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2124/)

Comment: r u sure about those?

Comment: Wouldn't have answered if I were not, @servantofWiser

Comment: whats the reference?

Comment: @zed111 added (although it was provided in the related answer).

Comment: The [sunni point of view](http://islamqa.info/en/2458) is that, the person is required to do wudu is he sees any of those liquids.

Answer (score 0):

> I used to get emotional urethral discharge frequently. Being the
> son-in-law of the Prophet (ﷺ) I requested a man to ask him about it.
> So the man asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about it. The Prophet (ﷺ) replied,
> "Perform ablution after washing your organ (penis)." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:269

Before praying you can do as described in the hadith. Rest is not in your control, so you continue with prayer, just like a person who has urine retention problem. These people are advised to take ablution and pray even if urine comes during praying.

> I felt greatly distressed by the frequent flowing of prostatic fluid.
> For this reason I used to take a bath very often. I asked the apostle
> of Allah (ﷺ) about this. He replied: Ablution will be sufficient for
> you because of this. I asked: Messenger of Allah, what should I do if
> it smears my clothes. He replied: It is sufficient if you take a
> handful of water and sprinkle it on your clothe when you find it has
> smeared it. https://sunnah.com/abudawud:210