# How to attain full purity? Please see details

Tags: practical-islam, sex, taharah, ghusl, islamqa

Assalamoalaikum.

I have a question in my mind from past few days.

The question is that after having sexual intercourse or, say, after masturbating one does ghusl to attain purity. But what if some semen remained in the urinary tract of penis and after a small time of doing ghusl he do pee and that semen came out that time. What would be done in this situation? Do he needs to do ghusl again?

Please give a nice answer with some relevant reference, if any.

Jazakallah hu khair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About pre ejaculation fluid](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23317/about-pre-ejaculation-fluid)

Comment: Ghusl is only required when semen is ejaculated as a result of a sexual act (literally ejaculation by contraction of mmuscles). But if just some semen comes out without any sexual excitement and it wasn't ejaculation, then no need yo do ghusl, just wash the private part and have wudu'.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel Jazakallah hu khair akhi. Are you sure about this? Please post a reference too, if any.

Comment: Here https://islamqa.info/en/105781 , the answer here doesn't answer the same question, but it has the answer for your question. It says that ghusl us required only when semen us ejaculated in gushes or spurts, accompanied by sexual pleasure.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel Jazakallah hu khair, brother. You just took off a great burden from my head.  Alhamdulillah, now I can say I'm totally paak (pure).

Comment: brother you have to take bath if it is remaining fluid of semen called as Istibra and masturbating is forbidden in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, briefly speaking, you ought to do Ghusl (an ablution that you wash all of your body by its conditions ...) or  for both items as you mentioned. Actually, seemingly, it is a logical view (at least according to Shia, I am not aware of Sunni brothers view about that) that is said to do urine after doing ..., why? In order to exit all of the semen from the channel (and not to remain anymore ... and in order to prevent such troubles...

So, seemingly, you should do Ghusl for both cases, but do urine after ... to exit all of the semen in order to confident regarding lack of semen.

Answer (score 0):

Walecum assalam!

To be on safe side, its better to perform Ghusl. (just to avoid any risk) as i cannot find any scholarly evidence of this issue, you should better consult an Islamic scholar about it. Till you don't get the answer, keep doing ghusl again, when you see semen in urine after ghusl.

Answer (score 0):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Walekumussalam,

> Ali RA narrated: "I asked the Prophet about Al-Madhi. He said: "For
>   Al-Madhi is Wudu, and for AI-Mani is Ghusl."(Tirmidhi)

I am providing reference according to Hanafi Fiqh

There are three types of fluid 1.Mazi 2.Mani 3.Wadi

Mazi is a thin white fluid which comes due to stimulation and does not need Ghusl but requires wudhu.

Mani is a thick white spurting fluid comes after sexual ejaculation it requires Ghusl if comes due to sexual pleasure or Shahwat.

Wadi is a sticky fluid comes after urination it requires wudhu but does not require Ghusl.

It is mentioned in Al Marja us Sabiq that if mani came and have taken bath before urination and before 40 steps have taken and have performed prayers then the prayer is valid then he sees some fluid it is the remaining mani left at that time and coming out later so he should perform ghusl again.But if person has taken 40 steps or taken a nap and then took bath then it would not be considered as mani and thus does not require Ghusl.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Alaikom Salam,

The extraction of semen is **not** the reason for ghusl.  Bathing is obligatory after sex, even if you did not ejaculate;  the mere act of sexual intercourse requires ghusl.

**أَو لامَستُمُ النِّساءَ**

**...or you have been in contact with women** (Quran 4:43)

In *Sahih Muslim*, through Matar from Abu Huraira, it's reported the Prophet said:

**إِذَا جَلَسَ بَيْنَ شُعَبِهَا الأَرْبَعِ ثُمَّ جَهَدَهَا فَقَدْ وَجَبَ عَلَيْهِ الْغُسْلُ ‏ وَإِنْ لَمْ يُنْزِلْ" ‏"**

**"If one of you sits between her legs and penetrates her, Ghusl is obligatory, even if there is no ejaculation/orgasm."**

From both of these, ghusl isn't required just because of semen coming out.

Comment: this means that one do not have to do ghusl in the situation described in the question?